# Creating and using attributes in XSLT

Tags: xslt, attributes, unique

I'm trying to write xsl that would take something like this:

```
<Invoices>
  <Invoice>
    <Customer>
      <Type>P</Type>
      <First>John</First>
      <Last>Doe</Last>
      <Id>123-45</Id>
    </Customer>
    <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
  </Invoice>
  <Invoice>
    <Customer>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <Name>ACME Inc</Name>
      <Id>765-432</Id>
    </Customer>
    <Amount>3456.78</Amount>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

and produce something like this:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer type="Person" ref="1">
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</Lastname>
    <Id>123-45</Id>
  </Customer>
  <Customer type="Company" ref="2">
    <Name>ACME Inc</Name>
    <Id>765-432</Id>
  </Customer>
<Customers>
<Invoices>
  <Invoice>
    <Recipient>1</Recipient>
    <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
  </Invoice>
  <Invoice>
    <Recipient>2</Recipient>
    <Amount>3456.78</Amount>
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

I.e. the customers should be listed separately with each having an unique ref-attribute and then the invoices should use that attribute to reference the recipient. One of the things causing me problems is that the schema for the output defines the "ref"-attribute having type long, so I can't directly use the value of Id-element, which contains non-numeric characters. I can use e.g. position() to get unique reference, but how do I keep track of the references used?

Comment: It seems you want to process elements twice, so use two modes, to generate the numbers use `xsl:number`.

Comment: If you run `<xsl:for-each select="Invoice">` twice, you will get the same values of `position()`on each run. (This is assuming each invoice has exactly one customer).